# Can we find an example about absolute maximum?

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Can we find an example for: A function $f(x)$ that is continuous for $−5< x <5$, has an absolute maximum at $x= 0$, and has no absolute minimum on $[−3,3]$.

Comment: Are you sure the question didn't say $(-3,3)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous on $(-5,5)$, it is also continuous on $[-3,3]$, so by the Extreme Value Theorem, it achieves a minimum on the closed interval $[-3,3]$.